# Lie Bracket and vector fields

Tags: manifolds

Could you please help me solve it? Let X and Y be smooth vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $[X,Y]=0$ (Lie bracket). Show that around each point there exists local diffeomorphism f such that $f_*(X)=∂/∂x$ and $f_*(Y)= ∂/∂y$.

Comment: Have you looked at John M. Lee's book? (http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Smooth-Manifolds-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387954481)

Comment: go with the flow.

Comment: This is the Frobenius theorem and you can check it on wiki.